# Why setState isn't re-rendering or working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to trigger re-render when user post a comment. So I used setState. Doesn't seem to re-render.
I want to re-render every time on handle submit.

I just edit it so it not a promise; my mistake on that one. But it doesnt seem to work re-render.

this is the container where this.state.comments come from. Its only pre-writing it. So i don't have to do it in the constructor.

```
import React from 'react';

class CreateForm extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = this.props.comment;
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    };

    handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.createComment(this.state);
        this.setState({body: ''});

    };

    update(field) {
        return e => this.setState({ [field]: e.currentTarget.value });
    }

    handleDelete(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.deleteComment(this.props.comment.id);
    }

    render() {

        return (
          <div className='comment-form'>
            <h2 className='comment-h2'>Comment</h2>
            <form className='inside-comment-form' onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}

            >
              <textarea
                className='comment-input'
                type='text'
                placeholder='Join the discussion'
                onChange={this.update("body")}
                value={this.state.body}
              />

              <input
                type='submit'
                value={this.props.formType}
              />
            </form>
          </div>
        );
    }
};




const mstp = (state, ownProps) => { 
    const news = ownProps.match.params.newspaperId;
    return ({
        comment: {
            body: '',
            newsId: news
        },
        formtype: 'Post Comment'

    })
};
```

Comment: Is `createComment` returning a Promise that resolves?

Comment: I just edit so it doesnt return a promise. But it doesnt re-render.

Comment: It's still unclear, could you describe exactly what is rendered, what you'd like it to render after submitting and also include a [mcve]?

Comment: So the reason i want to re-render because if a user leave a comment on an article The comment goes on a different article also. Unless the page refresh, the comment on a different article will clear. So I want it to re-render so it will clear the state. And also, setState does put the {body: ''}, but it doesn't  render again

Comment: It was already clear why you want to re-render, what's unclear is what's happening exactly because the code you've shared should work. Maybe it re-renders already but with the same value because of a parent? This line comes to mind: `this.state = this.props.comment;`

Comment: So i added the container, this.props.comment is just from the container for form fill out;

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you have assigned props to state in constructor and The danger is that if the props on the component are changed without the component being ‘refreshed’, the new prop value will never be displayed because the constructor function (or initialisation) will never update the current state of the component. The initialisation of state from props only runs when the component is first created. for more info you can refers this awesome article [link](https://medium.com/@justintulk/react-anti-patterns-props-in-initial-state-28687846cc2e).

You can initialise empty state in constructor and in **componentDidUpdate** you can  check update in prevProps or prevState and Update the state using **setState** . This will cause re-rendering if any update in props.

I Hope this will solve your problem!!